# Wrapping Stack Exchange footer site list?

Tags: html, formatting, stackexchange, footers

Browsing through the [StackExchange Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/) website I came across this, and was curious whether wrapping of site names is correct.  Will a users eye automatically read "User" and wrap their eyes to the next line and reading "experience"?  Will this exclude users who read LTR languages?

[image: StackExchange Android Website]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a mistake.  They **should have used a non-breaking space** between 'user' and 'experience'.  In HTML it is represented as `&#160;` or `&nbsp;`.

I also looked at that and saw "user", and if it weren't for your red arrow, I wouldn't have seen the "experience" part of that, which is clearly not their intention.

Comment: Agree, it probably is a mistake. There was a post on [Meta.Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61733/use-non-breaking-spaces-in-the-footer-site-list/164852#164852) where this was originally raised. I've added a new answer to that question with info about it not working. (Interestingly there are some non-breaking spaces in some of the titles - 'home improvement' being one of them. Also all the StackExchange beta sites have non-breaking spaces in their titles, but these graduated sites don't seem to.

Comment: [HTTP Status Code 755 - Not enough semi-colons](https://github.com/joho/7XX-rfc)